# How to use Uno Lottie on Android?

Tags: android, uwp, uno-platform

Created simple animation like said here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/animations/lottie-scenarios/getting_started_json

```
<controls:AnimatedVisualPlayer AutoPlay="True" Width="90" Height="90">
    <lottie:LottieVisualSource UriSource="ms-appx:///Utils/17477-orange-payment.json"/>
<controls:AnimatedVisualPlayer>
```

It works on UWP, not working on Android.

What I have referenced:

```
UWP
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console">
      <Version>1.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter">
      <Version>1.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform">
      <Version>6.2.10</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie">
      <Version>6.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.UI.Xaml">
      <Version>2.3.200213001</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI">
      <Version>5.1.0-build.200.gf9c311b069</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Uno.UI">
      <Version>2.1.37</Version>
    </PackageReference>
```

```
Android
 <PackageReference Include="Com.Airbnb.Android.Lottie">
      <Version>3.0.4</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.UI.Xaml">
      <Version>2.3.200213001</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI">
      <Version>5.1.0-build.200.gf9c311b069</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Uno.UI" Version="2.2.0-dev.390" />
    <PackageReference Include="Uno.UI.Lottie">
      <Version>2.2.0-dev.390</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Uno.UniversalImageLoader" Version="1.9.32" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter" Version="1.1.2" />
```

The app is running without `NotImplementedException`, just transaparent on Android.
Any sample will be super!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your json file is not bundled/included properly?

On WASM, iOS and macOS, you can put the Lottie .json files directly in a folder of the shared project (for example "Lottie/myanimation.json") and set their Build action as Content.

On Android, Lottie .json files need to be added into the Assets folder. To match the same path as for the other platforms, the file could be stored at "Assets/Lottie/myanimation.json". Set its Build action to AndroidAsset.

To reference the animations in XAML, use the `ms-appx:` URI, in this case `ms-appx:///Lottie/myanimation.json`.

Also note on Android, the `Stretch` mode of `Fill` is not currently supported.

[Uno Lottie Documentation reference](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/371e78adf6ec6305c84ce9262e665871f03f1dd2/doc/articles/features/Lottie.md)

Other possibility but I notice your file contains "-", I know Android hates those characters in images, you could try to rename your file.